# Js Почему не видит переменную из скопа

Tags: javascript, jshint

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
'use strict';

let numberOfFilms;

function start() {
  numberOfFilms = +prompt('Сколько фильмов вы уже посмотрели', '');

  while (numberOfFilms == '' || numberOfFilms == null || isNaN(numberOfFilms)) {
    numberOfFilms = +prompt('Сколько фильмов вы уже посмотрели', '');
  }
}

start();
```

Comment: Что такое "скопа", и что у Вас не работает?

Comment: о какой переменной речь?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавил картинку с ошибкой. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: [Такой же вопрос с той же ошибкой, и тут есть ответ](https://qna.habr.com/q/730211)

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь это связано  с "use strict"

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов, и там есть ответ?

Comment: А что по вашему должен делать prompt при выполении в среде node.js? Это исключительно браузерная функция, выводящая вопрос на подобие алёрта, в node её нет и быть не может.

Comment: @theblackmonkey, перенесите 'use strict' в начало функции и все будет в порядке. Скорее всего ваша среда оборачивает код во что-то еще, а `'use strict'` должна быть в первой строке кода, что не соблюдается. Ну и код в браузере, конечно, запускайте.

Answer (score 2):

По предупреждению о "use strict":
"use strict" необходимо объявлять в каждой функции отдельно

```
(function () {
   'use strict';
   // this function is strict...
}());
```

Если же это вам не нравится, вы можете отключить это правило в jshint `/*jshint strict:false */`.
[Вопрос на английском stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462478/jslint-is-suddenly-reporting-use-the-function-form-of-use-strict)

На счёт prompt:
Это не связано с "use strict". Это связано с тем, что вы пытаетесь вызвать исключительно браузерную функцию `prompt` в среде `node.js`. В ноде нет такой функции, ведь она отвечает за вызов вопроса в окне **браузера**.

Comment: Вообщем я весь код завернул в фунцию добавив "use strict" и терминал перестал выдовать ошибку. Просто в фунции код не выдает ошибку. А если я ниже вызываю эту функцию (где весь код) код опять выдает ошибку. Я еще не дашел до изучения nodejs, обьясните мне пожалуйста.

Comment: Что вам не понятно? Вы запускаете скрипт командой node, соответственно он работает в среде Node.js. Как запустить скрипт в браузере, вы можете легко найти в гугле.